# Closed stream when consuming big messages from GCP pubsub

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-java

I am using:

spring-boot 2.2.10
spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub 1.2.5
google-cloud-pubsub 1.108.0
google-cloud-core 1.93.7
gax 1.57.1
grpc-core 1.30.2

I am consuming messages of different sized from a GCP subscription. When a "big" message is sent to my client library:

1º It never reaches my listener code (I put a dumb logger)
2º I can see "Received data on closed stream"
3º Message is never acked, never dequed, never dlq-ed
4º Message is sent to my service over and over (sent count metric keeps going)

I know gRPC max size problem was already solved time ago, so gRPC keepAlive ... so I am lost on leads to investigate.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Alyson I wasnt. I tried to contact spring-cloud people about this but didnt got any answer. My suspect is this is related the size of the messages (as I said) but that is expected to be solved long ago, so it makes no sense.

Comment: @Alyson Please let me know about your findings if you manage to make any progress around this, please.